# Setting a location in Map View

Tags: android

I'm using a map view and what I want is to mark all the ex. starbucks that near me.
but I don't have any idea how to do this.
Right now  all I can do is to view my current location.

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemizedOverlay to display multiple markers in android, to understand how itemized overlay works, and what it is refer following links, and tutorials:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/using-itemizedoverlay-to-add-marker-on.html

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MyMap extends MapActivity{

    MapView mapView;
    MapController mapController;

    /* positon */
    double latitude = Your latitude; 
    double longitude = Your longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YourLayout);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(8); 
        GeoPoint pointRabat = new GeoPoint(microDegres(latitude),
                microDegres(longitude));
        mapController.setCenter(pointRabat);
    }

    private int microDegres(double value) {
        return (int) (value * 1000000);
    }

@Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

for add overlay

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       GeoPoint pointRabat = new GeoPoint(microDegres(latitude),
                    microDegres(longitude));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "My Current Location", "My Current Location");
        overlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);

    }
```

Comment: Yes it show the current location with zoom you want add a marker to location ??

Comment: I already done with this. now what I'm need to do is to mark a specific location near my location for example all the starbucks that near.